# 32 bit hex in one variable

Tags: c

How can I put this hex 0x0a01 into a 32 bit var in C. What I'm trying to do is to parse a protocol. Part of the it has a length value. The problem is that I'm getting the received packet as an array, so the length 0x0a01 would be 0x0a on lets say [1] and 0x01 on [2], and I want them both to be 0a01 in one var so I can run a compare to a constant or use in a for loop.

Comment: Welcome to Programmers.  This is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development.  This question would be ontopic at StackOverflow.  For more information read the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 6):

ah 32 bit is a `int` in most current platforms (or `int32_t` defined in stdint.h)

and bit operations are made for this:

```
int var = buff[1]<<8|buff[2];
```

`<<` is the left shift so `0x0a` gets transformed into `0x0a00` and `|` is the or operator so that is gets combined properly

Comment: +1 If you want to be guaranteed that the var is 32 bit, use `int32_t` or `uint32_t` from `limits.h`. Also, the standard permits for `int` to be 16 bit, but requires `long` to be at least 32.

Comment: @AdamZalcman: the C99 fixed-width types (`typedef`s), if available, are defined in `<stdint.h>`, not `<limits.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t var;
char buff[128];

...

var = ((buff[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (buff[2] & 0xFF);
```

Notice we use `(buff[1] & 0xFF) << 8` and not `buff[1] << 8`, because if `buff` is a `char` array and `char` is signed, sign extension would occur on the promoted `buff[1]` when the value is negative.